# What is the best way to display the frames rendered by the camera when making 2d games in java

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a simple game engine in java, I display the frames renderer the camera using `g2d.drawImage(frame)` & I used `jframe.repaint()` to clear the screen so I can draw the next frame again but when I run a game the screen turns white the draw image than it repeat this again & again
so how I can do that without this problem

Comment: `JFrame` (and top level containers in general) are not double buffered, which is why it isn't recommended to override their `paint` methods.  Instead, start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method (don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`).  I'd also recommend using a Swing `Timer` as the main loop to update the state and schedule repaints

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for more details

Comment: If you need something that is more "performant" and not tied to the Swing paint engine, you should look at [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) which gives you complete control over the painting process

Comment: You can use `java.awt.image.BufferStrategy`, it essentially draws the frames while keeping a buffer of the next frame in it's memory, i.e it renders the frame when it has already finished drawing the next frame in the memory, so there won't be any lag between drawing frames

Comment: You could also use the `JPanel` and set double buffered to `true`(it is already set true by default), so that it makes the next frame before rendering the current frame.

Comment: thank you @MadProgrammer I Just used the BufferStrategy and it worked